# SQLAlchemy not finding table to generate foreign key

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to migrate my database but I am unable to do so because this error shows up when I try to migrate

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'joinedServers.server_id' could not find table 'servers' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

The secondary the table joinedServers is for some reason unable to find the servers table even though I'm pretty sure I set up the table and relationship correctly.

This is my servers table

```
from .db import db
from .joinedServer import joinedServers

class Server(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = "servers"

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
   topic = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)

   channels = db.relationship("Channel", cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True, back_populates="server")
   server_users = db.relationship("User", secondary=joinedServers, back_populates="joined_servers")
```

This is my secondary table

```
from .db import db

joinedServers = db.Table(
   "joinedServers",
   db.Column("server_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("servers.id"), primary_key=True),
   db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)
)
```

This is the other table I am connecting to through the secondary

```
from .joinedServer import joinedServers


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
   __tablename__ = 'users'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   username = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False, unique=True)
   email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
   hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

   messages = db.relationship("Message", back_populates="user")
   joined_servers = db.relationship("Server", secondary=joinedServers, back_populates="server_users")
```

I have no clue why this is happening and would appreciate some explanations on how to fix it.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this?